# Are there any keyboard shortcuts for RadioButton and Checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, keyboard-shortcuts, radio-button

I have a lot of data-entryists using my ASP.NET application and we have all been wondering if there are any keyboard keys or shortcuts that you can press to trigger:

- Check a RadioButton
- Uncheck a RadioButton
- Check a Checkbox
- Uncheck a Checkbox

I know that you can write Javascript and do it yourself, but do any keyboard keys/shortcuts already exist without using the mouse?

Comment: good Question. i want to Know manually setting Shortcut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> is the standard button for those, with arrow keys to move between radio buttons.